# Anonymous callback with arguments. what actually happens?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sample code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("foo.txt", "utf8", (error, data) => {
 if (error) {
 throw error;
 }
 console.log(data);
});
```

where is the anonymous callback getting the arguments for its parameters (error and data)?

Comment: `fs.readFile` supplies the values when it invokes the callback. This is how callbacks work.

Comment: Like any other function: they are supplied when it's called. In this case from within `fs.readFile`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the fs module returns these two arguments. If it fails to read "foo.txt" then the error will be thrown. If however, "foo.txt" is successfully read, then the data object will be returned.

You can read more about it in the node documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#callback-example

I understand that it looks confusing, I remember thinking: "how can these arguments have values when there's nothing that's being passed in?". The thing is that you just can't see where these arguments have come form, and in this case, you just have to trust the docs. Or, if you're particularly keen you can take a dive into the source code.

Comment: I find the words "thrown" and "returned" in this answer misleading. The callback is called with either `error` or `data` being not `undefined`, but no `return` or `throw` statement is involved.

Comment: Quite right Thomas, these technical words may be misleading to the seasoned developer. What do you think of replacing `returns` with `passes in`, `thrown` with `defined` and `returned` with `defined`?