# Mysql server - failing to insert large image file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to insert an image that is 1MB or higher, I get this error

> MySQL server has gone away  or Fatal error: Allowed memory size of
> 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14073856 bytes) in
> C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.1.1\libraries\classes\Response.php on line
> 345

Yet the field is long blob and says (max 128 MiB)

What is the problem and how to resolve it?

I changed `max_allowed_packet = 16M` to `max_allowed_packet = 128M` in the `my.ini` file
and expected large image file to upload but the issue persists

Comment: I believe this might be the route to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is. MySQL crashing or PHP fatal memory error? PHP memory issue wont be addressed with mysql configuration changes.

Comment: Why does your code try to allocate 14MB? Ah, it's not your code, it's phpmyadmin, I'll add that tag.

Comment: Please note that, as the person asking a question, it is expected of you to respond, in some way, to people taking the effort to answer your question. You didn't react to the comments and answer on [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73949337/anonymous-callback-with-arguments-what-actually-happens) and you're absent here. We have a lot of people here, asking low quality questions, and then ignore all comments and answers. Don't be one of those.